# If i don't tag a column as NULL while creating a table, is it considered NULL?

Tags: sql-server

If i don't tag a column as NULL while creating a table, is it considered NULL? Lets say I forgot to put null or not null into a specific column like MasterCustomerAddress Column. Is it tagged as NULL automatically?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ODSMasterCustomer]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [ODSMasterCustomer]
    Go
    Create Table ODSMasterCustomer 
    (MasterCustomerID int NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY, 
    MasterCustomerName nvarchar(160)NULL, 
    MasterCustomerNotes nvarchar(800)NULL,
    MasterCustomerAddress nvarchar(255),
    )
```

Comment: yes it will contains null values ....

Comment: Seriously, wouldn't it have been easier to just try it out. Plus you memorize it better by playing around!

Comment: I must agree trying it yourself would've been better, especially considering the amount of effort it would've taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All columns are nullable, by default, *except* for column(s) that form the `PRIMARY KEY`. Since the primary key doesn't allow nulls, all columns participating in the primary key are automatically marked as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I have an Idea that NULL is the default, however I thought of asking this anyway just to get a PROFESSIONAL answer like this. One that would also be beneficial not only to me but also to other green horned sql devs like me who might come across on the same question in the future

Answer (score 0):

If null value left blank, it assumes null by default.

Comment: Ok. Im just making sure because I have bunch of stored procedures to insert on this table. Thanks!